# DataTable with a byte[] field as parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, table-valued-parameters

I've been reusing this method of using a DataTable as a parameter to a stored procedure and it's been working great. This is the simplified working code:

```cs
using (dbEntities dbe = new dbEntities())
{
    var dt = new dataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("Message");
    dt.Columns.Add("CreatedOn", typeof(DateTime));

    foreach (var row in randomDataSource)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(
            row.id,
            row.message,
            DateTime.Now
            );
    }

    var tableType = new SqlParameter("tableType", SqlDbType.Structured);
    tableType.Value = dt;
    tableType.TypeName = "[dbo].[RandomTableType]";

    dbe.ExecuteStoreCommand(
        "EXEC [dbo].[SaveTable] @tableType",
        new object[] { tableType }
        );
}
```

The problem arises when the field I want to add is of a binary type. i.e.:

```cs
dt.Columns.Add("BinaryMessage", typeof(byte[]));
```

The corresponding column in the database is `varbinary(MAX)` by the way. When I try to run this, I get this error:

> Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is
>   not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

How do I modify what I have to make this work?

Comment: as you may know byte[] is not a datatype , use byte instead of

Comment: But an array is a datatype...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The representation for a binary string in .NET is the [`SqlBinary` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.aspx).

You want to add your column like this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("BinaryMessage", typeof(SqlBinary));
```

The `SqlBinary` class has an [explicit conversion to a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136675.aspx) and an [implicit conversion from a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.op_implicit.aspx), so the value from a byte array to the column is a simple matter of assignment, while getting a byte array from the column requires an explicit cast.

Comment: +1 Well found!  It would be clearer if the code that sends the `DataTable` off to SQL Server threw an exception for a `typeof(byte[])` column.  The SQL Server error message is anything but clear.

Comment: @casperOne - Thank you for posting this answer - it really helped me out! Unfortunately, [I've encountered a similar problem in an edge case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782496/empty-datatable-causes-errors-when-table-valued-parameter-has-varbinary-types). I'd love to hear if you have any thoughts :-)

Comment: This is a little gem. Still saving people from much pain over 10 years later! The issue of datablob handling still hasn't improved.